# Maven coordinates terminology

Tags: maven, maven-3

What is the terminology for the following Maven coordinates situations?

(I've included possible terms underneath each situation, in case no term currently exists for it)

1. have groupId, artifactId & version that might or might not actually resolve to an artifact in a specific repository

   - resolvable coordinates
2. have groupId, artifactId & version that resolves to an artifact in a specific repository

   - valid coordinates
3. have groupId, artifactId & version that does not resolve to an artifact in a specific repository

   - unknown coordinates
   - invalid coordinates
   - unfound coordinates
4. have groupId & artifactId, but no version

   - unversioned coordinates
5. have groupId & artifactId; might or might not have version

   - identified coordinates (I'm not a huge fan of this, but haven't yet thought of anything better)
6. have groupId, artifactId & version, plus at least one of packaging or classifier

   - extended coordinates